# problems about pthread_rwlock_wrlock and pthread_rwlock_wrlock

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_rwlock_t rwlock = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;

void *func(void *arg)
{
        while (1) {
                printf("begin\n");
                pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
                printf("fall through wrlock\n");
                pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
                printf("fall through wrlock\n");
                pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
                printf("fall through unlock\n");
                pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
                printf("end\n");
        }
}

int main()
{
        pthread_t thd;
        pthread_create(&thd, NULL, func, NULL);

        sleep(100);
}
~
```

I write code above on UBUNTU 10.04 and run,
It just output

root@ubuntu:~# ./a.out

```
begin
fall through wrlock
fall through wrlock
fall through unlock
end
begin
```

..and finally block here

Why it does not block when the first time 
the second 
pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock) 
called

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Results are undefined if the calling thread holds the read-write lock (whether a read or write lock) at the time the call is made.

This is from [the Open Group page on `pthread_rwlock_wrlock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_rwlock_wrlock.html).

What you're doing is undefined, at least in that version of the spec. You're lucky that vicious monkeys didn't fly in through the window and beat you to death :-)

---

In any case, you really should be checking the return code from all your pthread functions. They *can* fail, and you really don't want to continue on the assumption you have a lock when in fact you *don't,* since that sort of negates the usefulness of locks.

That same page linked to above states:

> The `pthread_rwlock_wrlock()` and `pthread_rwlock_trywrlock()` functions may fail if:
>        `[EINVAL]` - the value specified by rwlock does not refer to an initialised read-write lock object.
>        `[EDEADLK]` - the current thread already owns the read-write lock for writing or reading.

I'd be checking to see if you're actually getting back the `EDEADLK` error code. This error code is a possibility even in [the latest editions of POSIX threads](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_trywrlock.html) where, as Nemo points out in a comment, the "undefined" wording has been removed.

---

One thing is still a worry however. The latest spec states that the "calling thread **may** deadlock if at the time the call is made it holds the read-write lock" (my bold).

I see this as an *actual* deadlock, ie, the thread totally locks up. The `EDEADLK` error code section also states that the "`pthread_rwlock_wrlock()` function **may** fail if ..." (again, my bold).

Both those statements have the weasel word "may" in them, so it's still not clearly defined which will happen in any given situation. It may (no pun intended) be that this was left unspecified because certain implementations behaved differently (it's not always easy to detect a deadlock situation in advance) although that's pure speculation on my part.

Bottom line, unless you *know* you have a recursive lock of some sort (where you can relock with impunity), don't do it.

Comment: +1, although interestingly, that wording no longer appears in [the latest spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_trywrlock.html)

Comment: @Nemo, it still has the EDEADLK error code which is what I expect is happening, hence my update.

Comment: Better :-).  No longer undefined behavior, I believe, for the second lock.  `EDEADLCK` is almost certainly what is happening here, followed by undefined behavior on the second unlock.

Comment: @Nemo: How so? It's a "may fail" not "shall fail".

Comment: @R.., after a bit more investigation you may be right. It appears to allow either a real deadlock or an error code of "would deadlock if I let you try this". While that's not as bad as undefined behaviour, it's still seems less than fully specified, so it's probably best not to rely on it one way or the other.

Comment: "The calling thread may deadlock if at the time the call is made it holds the read-write lock (whether a read or write lock)."

Comment: @R., I read the current spec as saying the behavior is implementation-defined, not undefined...  And indeed limited either to deadlocking or to failing with `EDEADLK`.  So my bet is that the second lock attempt failed with `EDEADLK`, leaving the rwlock locked.  The first unlock then succeeded, leaving it unlocked; and the second unlock invoked undefined behavior (corrupting the state of the rwlock).

Comment: I agree with your analysis of what happened and interpretation of the spec.